# Using pqgrid to export excel

Tags: javascript, excel, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

Here, I have a question about pqgrid.

```
var newObj = {
        width: 1500,
        height: 600,
        title: "channel <b>roi</b>",
        resizable: true,
        scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
        editModel: { clicksToEdit: 2 },
        dataModel: { data: obj.data },
        draggable:false,
        freezeCols:7,
        selectionModel: { type: 'cell', mode: 'block' },
        colModel: CM,
        pageModel: {type:'local'},
        toolbar: {
            cls: 'pq-toolbar-export',
            items: [{
                    type: 'button',
                    label: "Export to Excel",
                    icon: 'ui-icon-document',
                    listeners: [{
                        "click": function (evt) {
                            $("#grid_export").pqGrid("exportExcel", { url: getDownExcelURL(), sheetName: "pqGrid sheet" });
                        }
                    }]
            }]
        },
    };
```

That is the my option in pqgrid. I do not konw what error happend. 
please help me.

Comment: Pls post your error!

Comment: No error... I don't know how to use this pqgrid, and this page http://paramquery.com/demos shows a little. what should i do in springMVC?